# How can I work this superclass to be a protocol + extension instead of class?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have the following be a protocol+extension for the methods instead of a class to prevent it from being used as a class you could instantiate?

The problem I was having is that I couldn't get it to build with the custom init. Xcode kept complaining that I was using self, but calling super.init wasn't accepted either.

```
class Entity: NSObject
{
    var objectID: String?
    var createdAt: NSDate?
    var updatedAt: NSDate?

    required override init()
    {
    }

    required init(dictionary: Dictionary)
    {
        if let objectID = dictionary["objectId"] as? String
        {
            self.objectID = objectID
        }

        if let createdAt = dictionary["createdAt"] as? String
        {
            self.createdAt = NSDate.dateFromJSONDateString(createdAt)
        }

        if let updatedAt = dictionary["updatedAt"] as? String
        {
            self.updatedAt = NSDate.dateFromJSONDateString(updatedAt)
        }
    }

    func dictionaryRepresentation() -> Dictionary
    {
        var dict = Dictionary()

        if let objectID = objectID
        {
            dict["objectId"] = objectID
        }

        if let createdAt = createdAt
        {
            dict["createdAt"] = createdAt.JSONDateString()
        }

        if let updatedAt = updatedAt
        {
            dict["updatedAt"] = updatedAt.JSONDateString()
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

Basically I would like to achieve that all classes conforming to Entity have an objectID, createdAT and updatedAt and can be initialized with a dictionary and get a dictionaryRepresentation for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use protocol, protocol extension and struct for this task.

Basic protocol:

```
protocol Entitable {
    var objectID: String? { get set }
    var createdAt: NSDate? { get set }
    var updatedAt: NSDate? { get set }

    init()
}
```

Struct:

```
struct Entity:Entitable {
    var objectID: String?
    var createdAt: NSDate?
    var updatedAt: NSDate?

    init() {

    }
}
```

Extension:

```
extension Entitable {
    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self.init()

        if let objectID = dictionary["objectId"] as? String {
            self.objectID = objectID
        }

        if let createdAt = dictionary["createdAt"] as? String {
            self.createdAt = NSDate.dateFromJSONDateString(createdAt)
        }

        if let updatedAt = dictionary["updatedAt"] as? String {
            self.updatedAt = NSDate.dateFromJSONDateString(updatedAt)
        }
    }

    func dictionaryRepresentation() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

        if let objectID = objectID {
            dict["objectId"] = objectID
        }

        if let createdAt = createdAt {
            dict["createdAt"] = createdAt.JSONDateString()
        }

        if let updatedAt = updatedAt {
            dict["updatedAt"] = updatedAt.JSONDateString()
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```